# Grouping of the elements based on the field value using muenchian in XSLT1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

Request xml..

```
<tem:responseDA xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org">
<tem:outputData>   
<tem:dictionary id="AutoOutputs">    

<tem:list numOfItems="2">       
<tem:item>       
<tem:field dataType="double" name="DOWNPAYMENT">2000.00</tem:field>
</tem:item>     
<tem:item>       
<tem:field dataType="double" name="DOWNPAYMENT">3000.00</tem:field>
</tem:item>
</tem:list>  
<tem:list numOfItems="2">       
<tem:item>       
<tem:field dataType="string" name="CAMPAIGNCODE">A</tem:field>\
</tem:item>
<tem:item>       
<tem:field dataType="string" name="CAMPAIGNCODE">B</tem:field>
</tem:item>
</tem:list>   
<tem:list numOfItems="2">       
<tem:item>      
<tem:field dataType="double" name="BALLOONPAYMENT">4000.00</tem:field>
</tem:item>
<tem:item>       
<tem:field dataType="double" name="BALLOONPAYMENT">5000.00</tem:field>
</tem:item>
</tem:list>       
</tem:dictionary>
</tem:outputData>
</tem:responseDA>
```

Now I need to group the campaign based on the "numofitems" in the field.

Output should be..

```
<ns:FinalPricingQuoteResponse xmlns:ns="http://corp.alahli.com/middlewareservices/CreditVerificationService/1.1/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org">
<ns:PricingQuoteOutput>
<ns:Campaigns>
<ns:campaignNumber>A</ns:campaignNumber>
<ns:downPayment>2000.00</ns:downPayment>
<ns:ballonPayment>4000.00</ns:ballonPayment>
</ns:Campaigns>
<ns:Campaigns>
<ns:campaignNumber>B</ns:campaignNumber>
<ns:downPayment>3000.00</ns:downPayment>
<ns:ballonPayment>5000.00</ns:ballonPayment>
</ns:Campaigns>
</ns:PricingQuoteOutput>
</ns:FinalPricingQuoteResponse>
```

Could you please help me for the muenchian grouping for XSLT1.0.. 
Thanks in advance..

regards,
Inian

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're much more likely to get good responses here if you show what you have tried, in a form that allows others to reproduce the problem (this is of course difficult if you have no idea where to start).  Not showing your work can give the impression you haven't done any and just want others to do your work for you.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Do you have any updates on this question. Please provide me the code ASAP..

Comment: Hi team, I have changed the question as proper question in a new question...

Comment: You still need to provide the XSLT that you tried to use and the unsatisfactory result

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with Münchian grouping. Presumably you have 3 lists coming up each time (with a variable number of entries, you could do this:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
        xmlns:ns="http://corp.alahli.com/middlewareservices/CreditVerificationService/1.1/"
        xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xd"
        version="1.0">

        <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <ns:FinalPricingQuoteResponse>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tem:responseDA/tem:outputData/tem:dictionary" />
            </ns:FinalPricingQuoteResponse>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="tem:dictionary">
            <ns:PricingQuoteOutput>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tem:list[position()=1]" />
            </ns:PricingQuoteOutput>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="tem:list[position()=1]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tem:item/tem:field[@name='DOWNPAYMENT']" />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="tem:field[@name='DOWNPAYMENT']">
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
            <ns:Campaigns>
                <ns:campaignNumber><xsl:value-of select="/tem:responseDA/tem:outputData/tem:dictionary/tem:list[position()=2]/tem:item[position()=$pos]/tem:field"/></ns:campaignNumber>
                <ns:downPayment><xsl:value-of select="."/></ns:downPayment>
                <ns:ballonPayment><xsl:value-of select="../../../tem:list[position()=3]/tem:item[position()=$pos]/tem:field"/></ns:ballonPayment>
            </ns:Campaigns>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the two different XPath (pick one and stick to it) to select the matching fields. Of course that would depend on the sequence how the lists appear, which could be fragile. So a slightly more robust version would be:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
        xmlns:ns="http://corp.alahli.com/middlewareservices/CreditVerificationService/1.1/"
        xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xd"
        version="1.0">

        <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <ns:FinalPricingQuoteResponse>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tem:responseDA/tem:outputData/tem:dictionary" />
            </ns:FinalPricingQuoteResponse>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="tem:dictionary">
            <ns:PricingQuoteOutput>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tem:list[tem:item/tem:field[@name='DOWNPAYMENT']]" />
            </ns:PricingQuoteOutput>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="tem:list[tem:item/tem:field[@name='DOWNPAYMENT']]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tem:item/tem:field[@name='DOWNPAYMENT']" />
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="tem:field[@name='DOWNPAYMENT']">
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
            <ns:Campaigns>
                <ns:campaignNumber><xsl:value-of select="/tem:responseDA/tem:outputData/tem:dictionary/tem:list[tem:item/tem:field[@name='CAMPAIGNCODE']]/tem:item[position()=$pos]/tem:field"/></ns:campaignNumber>
                <ns:downPayment><xsl:value-of select="."/></ns:downPayment>
                <ns:ballonPayment><xsl:value-of select="../../../tem:list[tem:item/tem:field[@name='BALLOONPAYMENT']]/tem:item[position()=$pos]/tem:field"/></ns:ballonPayment>
            </ns:Campaigns>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope that helps and feel free to accept the answer